# How to FILTER Python list with multiple criteria?

Tags: python, list

I have this list comprehension which returns elements in the list `lst_fcflds` if they are not in the list `RROPFields`:

`nfld_rrop = [i for i in lst_fcflds if i not in RROPFields]`

and want a filter so that  if `OBJECTID` or  `SHAPE` are in lst_fclfds, they will also NOT be returned - like:

`nfld_rrop = [i for i in lst_fcflds if i not in RROPFields and not in ["OBJECTID","SHAPE"]]`

Comment: You just omitted  `i` . `nfld_rrop = [i for i in lst_fcflds if i not in RROPFields and i not in ["OBJECTID","SHAPE"]]`

Answer (score 7):

You're just missing one `i`

```
nfld_rrop = [i for i in lst_fcflds if i not in RROPFields and i not in ["OBJECTID","SHAPE"]]
                                                              ^
```

However for performance, I would add one step first to create a `set` so you can do faster membership lookups.

```
filters = set(RROPFields + ["OBJECTID", "SHAPE"])
nfld_rrop = [i for i in lst_fcflds if i not in filters]
```